# Why is this approximation of $\pi(n)$ so good, and how to get asymptotic expansion?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, approximation

Today I came across this formula, and I noticed it was pretty close to the number of prime less than or equal to $n$:

$$ \pi\left(n\right)\approx\frac{2}{5}(\sqrt[5]{2})n^{\frac{4}{5}}+\frac{n}{20}$$

In fact it is so close that from $1<n<10000$, the largest error is $5$, and for $n<1000000$:

$$\left|\pi\left(n\right)-\left(\frac{2}{5}\sqrt[5]{2}n^{\frac{4}{5}}+\frac{n}{20}\right)\right|<46$$

After that, the difference starts to grow quickly, so I guess we would need to add a term $\pm\frac{n}{x}$ at the end ?

How is it possible to get an approximation that good with a formula that simple? But more importantly, how to find the next terms in the asymptotic expansion ? (if that's what it is)

Comment: For the second question: No. $\pi(x)=\operatorname{li}(x)+O(\sqrt x\ln x)$, which is a formula strongly linked to RH and it is the best result if I remember it correctly. Despite the fact that we can calculate the fluctuation part using the zeros of Riemann zeta function, I don't think there's another method. A comment on the formula you given: I think it is a coincidence or a direct estimation since $\pi(x)\sim\frac x{\ln x}$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @ Francois Huppe (spelling) -- Your statement is not true in general for n < 1,000,000.  Let n = 999,999.  With your formula, pi(999,999) is approximately 78, 991.   pi(999,999) = 78,498 exactly.  The absolute value of the difference equals 493, compared to 46.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n^{\frac 45}$ is too small as the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) shows.  It is much less than $\frac n{\log n}$.  You can get a decent fit over a small range by choosing the constants.  For $n=10^{15}, n^{\frac 45}=10^{12}=\frac n{1000}$, while $\log (10^{15})\approx 34.5$ A term like $\frac nx$ will not help-it is just a change to the $\frac 1{20}$ coefficient you already have.  On the other hand, $\frac n{20}$ is much too large.  Once $n \gt e^{20} \approx 5 \cdot 10^8$, it alone is too large.  When you talk of things like counting prime numbers, you need *much* larger ranges to be impressed by a close fit.